# Page overlaps on a footer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a "wordpress" website. I am using a mobile footer plugin which only appears on mobile devices. The problem I am facing is the page overlaps the footer (on phone).

I tried z-index as well to make that div appear on the page and not behind the page but it seems not to work. Here's my css for mobile footer div:

```
#callbook {
    bottom: 0;
    height: 48px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 1);
}
```

I added the `padding-bottom:48px;` to the check if the div exists, and it does. The problem is the page is overlapping the footer div. Appreciate your help :)

Cheers~

Comment: Add your html markup as well.

Comment: You can get your HTML code from the view-source mode

Comment: How we will know where on page you are using this #callbool div. You should provide minimum html or any link to your problem.

Comment: I can't see any problem like footer overlapping page on your website (mobile and desktop).

Comment: I don't see any issues in Chrome's mobile view; what browser are you using to check?

Comment: I am using Chrome only. In inspect element search for "mobile-call" class you'll find the particular div.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri its the other way round, page is overlapping on the footer, hence you cannot see the mobile footer

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [your site](http://sunrisedentalsurgery.2080solutions.com.au), it seems that your z-index just wasn't high enough. Change `#callbook` z-index to `z-index: 9999;` and it shows right up.